# Flutter Remove specific Route using Getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I have Routes stack A => B => C.

I want to push the new B and remove the old B screen from C.

I found the function `Get.removeRoute(route)`, but I couldn't find the route of the old B screen to remove.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!!!

Comment: Please try this one, When you are navigate from B to C use Get.offToNamed and when you are back from C to B use Get.toNamed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Get.offNamed()
```

or

```
Get.offAllNamed()
```

and to route from c => b you can  route manually

Comment: I have tried it.But I encountered the problem then that BController was initialized and then deleted imediately.

Comment: you are using lazy put so you have to set fenix :true  
that will create your controller agin
    Get.lazyPut(() => RealTimeController(),fenix: true);